# Problem in clearing TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I have multiple TextInput React-native-paper inputs generated dynamically in table. whenever i put valuee and check that this value is greater or not from some specific value based on this it will show alert message and will clear the textinput but its doesnt clear it .
the problem is that how to clear textInput after when the textchange in textinput?

```
    const  updateObtainMarks =(RN,obtmarks, subtotalmarks)=>{
    
    if(obtmarks>subtotalmarks)
    {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            ToastAndroid.show('Obtain marks should be less then total', ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.TOP);
            
          } else
           {
            AlertIOS.alert('Obtain marks should be less then total');
          }
    }
    else{
        var index = rollNo.indexOf(RN);
        // alert(index);
        obtainmarks[index]=obtmarks;  
    }
    

}

   return(

           {

                allrollNos.map((item, index) => (
      
                    <DataTable.Row>
                        <DataTable.Cell>{item.studentid}</DataTable.Cell>
                        <DataTable.Cell>{item.studentname}</DataTable.Cell>
                        <DataTable.Cell>{item.rollno}</DataTable.Cell>
                        {/* <DataTable.Cell>{item.obtainmarks}</DataTable.Cell> */}
                        <DataTable.Cell>
                            {item.obtainmarks===' '? 
                            ( 
                                <TextInput
                                // label='marks'          
                                    mode='flat'
                                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                                    maxLength={3}
                                    style={{height:25, padding:2, width:'100%'}}
                                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                    
                                    // defaultValue={''} 
                                    onChangeText={value=> addObtainMarks(item.rollno,value, item.subTotmarks)}
                                />
                            ):
                            (
                                <TextInput
                                // label='marks'

                                    mode='flat'
                                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                                    maxLength={3}
                                    style={{height:25, padding:2, width:'100%', border:'none'}}
                                    // value={item.obtainmarks}
                                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                    defaultValue={item.obtainmarks}

                                    //onChange={e =>updateObtainMarks(item.rollno, e.target.value, item.subtotalmarks)}
                                     onChangeText={value=> updateObtainMarks(item.rollno,value, item.subTotmarks)}
                                />
                            )      
                        }
                        </DataTable.Cell>
                        <DataTable.Cell>{item.obtainmarks}</DataTable.Cell>
                        <DataTable.Cell>{item.subTotmarks}</DataTable.Cell>
                    </DataTable.Row>
                            
                ))}
```

);

Comment: try doing a console.log if really `obtmarks>subtotalmarks` is true or not.

Comment: i have check it , it true. once the alert show then the textinput disappear also i want to clear the text input that time when the obtmarks>subtotalmarks

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(allrollNos);

const  updateObtainMarks =(RN,obtmarks, subtotalmarks, index)=>{
    
    if(obtmarks>subtotalmarks)
    {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            ToastAndroid.show('Obtain marks should be less then total', ToastAndroid.SHORT, ToastAndroid.TOP);
            
          } else
           {
            AlertIOS.alert('Obtain marks should be less then total');
          }
    // add logic here
        const newData = [...data];
        newData[index].clearField = true;
        setData(newData);
    } 

}


 allrollNos.map((item, index) => (
      
                   .....
                                <TextInput
                                // label='marks'

                                    .....
                                    defaultValue={ item.clearField ? "" : item.obtainmarks }
                                    onChangeText={value=> updateObtainMarks(item.rollno,value, item.subTotmarks, index)}
                                />
                            )      
                        }.....
                            
                ))
```